# Saved Location on Preferance is allways null

Tags: android, gson, sharedpreferences

I try to save a location on my Preference. SavedLocation class store three variables: name, location and the location type. All look great until I try to read saved dates from Preference. The name and location type are stored perfectly but stored location is null. In debug savedlocation contain all wanted variable but look like `ed.putString(SAVED_LOCATIONS, gson.toJson(savedLocations, savedLocationsType))`;
 not write correct my dates.

```
private void saveLocation(SavedLocation savedlocation, Context context) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type savedLocationsType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SavedLocation>>() {}.getType();
    ArrayList<SavedLocation> savedLocations = getSavedLocations(context);
    savedLocations.add(savedlocation);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_LOCATIONS, gson.toJson(savedLocations, savedLocationsType));
    ed.apply();
}
```

SavedLocation class is alike:

```
 public SavedLocation(String name, Location location, LocationType type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.type = type;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try debugging your code first .. See if `savedLocations` have the locations and what does `#gson.toJson()` returns .

Comment: saved location have all required dates. gson.Json() return [{"location":{"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":0},"name":"test 1","type":"HOTEL"},{"location":{"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":0},"name":"test 2","type":"HOTEL"}]

Comment: When try to read I get right value for name and type. For location get next result: Location[null 0,000000,0,000000 hAcc=??? t=?!? et=?!? vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???]. On savedLocation variable (before save method) I have right address (on read is null) and GPS coordonations (on read have 0,000000,0,000000).

Comment: I guess you are having a Gson problem as you say the `toJson()` return value includes `"location":{"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":0}`. So, Gson doesn't seem to know what to do with a `Location` object inside your `SavedLocation` object. I don't know what's the way to make Gson work, but another option would be to just save the latitude and longitude of the `Location` as float/double fields in your `SavedLocation` class. Someone familiar with Gson will probably provide a proper answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Create variable for `SharedPreferences` and `Editor`.

```
  SharedPreferences pref;
  Editor editor;
  String PREF_NAME="my_location"
```

Now get preference

```
    pref = this.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
    editor = pref.edit();
```

Now add location to `preference`

```
  editor.putString(SAVED_LOCATIONS, gson.toJson(savedLocations, savedLocationsType));
    editor.commit();
```

Then fetch the data

```
  String location=pref.getString(savedLocations, "defaultvalue");
```

Comment: I use savedLocations as a class with three different variables: name, location and type of location. And need to store more than one location.

Comment: Then use `room database` or `sqllite  database`.